# Create a dictionary from a Codable struct with all CodingKeys and values

Tags: swift, codable

Is it possible to associate the stored values of properties in a `Codable` `struct` with the `CodingKeys` of said properties, and return them without manual configuration of each struct?

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    
    let propertyOne: String = "Value One"
    let propertyTwo: String = "Value Two"
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case propertyOne = "Coding Key One"
        case propertyTwo = "Coding Key Two"
    }
    
    func allValues() -> [String: String] {

    /*
     
     return something like: [
        "Coding Key One": "Value One",
        "Coding Key Two": "Value Two"
     ]
     
     */

    }
}
```

Using `Mirror()` doesn't help much because it returns a label which is the property's name as a `String`, but I require the CodingKey. And `CaseIterable` doesn't get the values of the stored properties.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JSONSerialization` to get your dictionary

```
func allValues() throws -> [String: String] {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] ?? [:]
}
```